# Why is Pickle not serializing my array of classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm trying to serialize a large number of custom classes to disk using python's pickle. However, the classes aren't serializing properly.

Having looked at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it's my understanding what I'm trying to do ought to work, but perhaps it's not simply because I'm not understanding something.

My classes are defined at the top-level of the module. And no PicklingError exception is being fired when trying to pickle.

Here is my sample code. Uncomment Save() to serialize; uncomment Load() to load. When loading, the Synonyms array of Term isn't being populated, but the Main object of Term is being deserialized. You can see this by inspecting the "loadedTerms" object being returned from the Load() function.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import pickle

class Entry:
    Text = ""

    def __init__(self, text):
       self.Text = text

class Term:

    Main = None
    Synonyms = []


def Save():
    term = Term()
    term.Main = Entry("Dog")
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Canine"))
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Pursue"))
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Follow"))
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Plague"))

    terms = []
    terms.append(term)

    with open('output.pickle', 'wb') as p:
        pickle.dump(terms, p)

def Load():
    loadedTerms = []

    with open('output.pickle', 'rb') as p:
        loadedTerms = pickle.load(p)

    return loadedTerms


#Save()
#terms = Load()
```

Comment: Classes are pickled by name. Pickling a class won't save its state, and unpickling it won't try to generate a new copy of the class or restore the state of the class at the time of pickling.

Comment: Pretty sure your class definitions aren't doing what you think they are doing either. But as far as I can tell, your `Synonyms` attribute *is* being populated

Comment: I am still confused. I apologize for being dense. What good is it to pickle an object, then? And why is it pickling the "Main" object (I can deserialize it fine), but not elements of the array 'Synonyms'. 

The docs say, "Note that none of the class’s code or data is pickled, so in the following example the class attribute attr is not restored in the unpickling environment:"

But then it turns around and says, "Similarly, when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are pickled."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you explain? I'd love to learn.

Comment: @Ben I think fundamentally your issue is understanding the distinction between class-level attributes, sometimes called "static" attributes in other languages (which you use here), and *instance* attributes. See Daniel's answer.

Comment: Also, you aren't using arrays, you are using *lists*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I see. Thanks for the response. Are you saying that Main/Synonyms are "static" to the class Term?

Comment: Yes. Although that isn't the python terminology, but yes. And what you are actually doing in your `Text.__init__` here: `self.Text = text` is *shadowing* the static variable `Text` with an *instance* variable `text`. So you have a useless static variable hanging around...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Okay. Thanks. I come from a C++ background, and so I guess I have some learning to do still. I appreciate your responses.

Comment: @Ben yes, the class system is different in Python than C++. Python's class system is based on a language called Modula-3. It is actually *simpler* in My opinion. But basically, everything you define at the class level in your class defintion *belongs to the class object* (classes themselves are just another object in Python) and everything you assign to `self.attr = val` in a method will belong to *the instance*. The official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is quite good and worth a read-through.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga great, thanks. I'm finding Python beautiful, but I'm still learning the fundamentals. I will take the time to read said tutorial more carefully. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle only saves the instance attributes of a class, but `Synonyms` is a list, defined at class level. You should create the list in a `__init__`-method:

```
import pickle

class Entry:
    def __init__(self, text):
       self.Text = text

class Term:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Main = None
        self.Synonyms = []

def Save():
    term = Term()
    term.Main = Entry("Dog")
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Canine"))
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Pursue"))
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Follow"))
    term.Synonyms.append(Entry("Plague"))

    terms = []
    terms.append(term)

    with open('output.pickle', 'wb') as p:
        pickle.dump(terms, p)

def Load():
    with open('output.pickle', 'rb') as p:
        loadedTerms = pickle.load(p)
    return loadedTerms
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, this makes sense. One last question: you say that "Synonyms" is a list, defined at class level. But is Main not also defined at class level in my example?

Comment: You redefine `Main` in the second line of  `Save` as an instance attribute.

Comment: Aha! So I *use* synonyms - which is declared at class level - because I refer to it explicitly through the .append() call...but I REDEFINE Main by setting it equal to something. 

Okay. As you can tell I'm very green still with python. My background is in the C-language world. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions in such an informative manner.

Comment: So you *shadow* the "static" main on the *instance namespace* when you do `term.Main = Entry("Dog")`, creating an instance variable `Name`. Now the static `Main` is inaccesible from the instance, since it will always use it's instance variable `Main`.

Comment: Thanks so much all!